# How do I import modules in the Factor interpreter?

Tags: import, module, interpreter, factor-lang

I'm following the Sam's [decipher tutorial](http://www.rfc1149.net/blog/2007/01/18/factor-a-stack-based-programming-language/). When he does `8 group`, on my computer Factor gripes that it doesn't know the `group` function.

```
( scratchpad ) "01101001001000000110011001110101011000110110101101100101011001000010000001111001011011110111010101110010001000000110110101101111011011010000110100001010011000010110111001100100001000000110111001101111011101110010000001100110011011110111001000100000011110010110111101110101"

--- Data stack:
"0110100100100000011001100111010101100011011010110110010101100..."
( scratchpad ) 8 group
1: 8 group
          ^
No word named “group” found in current vocabulary search path

The following restarts are available:

:1      Use the grouping vocabulary
:2      Use the unix.ffi vocabulary
:3      Use the unix.groups vocabulary
4 :res  Defer word in current vocabulary

Type :help for debugging help.
```

Apparently `group` is located in the [grouping module](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-group,grouping.html), but I don't know how to import the module in the interpreter (something like `+m module` in Haskell's GHCi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interpreter, type `USE: grouping ;` to add a single vocabulary to the search path, or `USING: a b c ;` to add a list of vocabularies.

Documentation: [USE:](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-USE__colon__%2Csyntax.html) [USING:](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-USING__colon__%2Csyntax.html).